# How do I test the workflow I just created in ServiceNow

Tags: workflow, servicenow

I'm a developer and want to integrate with ServiceNow. Im new to ServiceNow and I have probably a very simple question. I created a workflow in the worflow canvas and validated and published it. When I click the play button nothing happens. Here is the  [document](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Creating_a_Workflow#gsc.tab=0) I followed.

How do I know that the workflow is working? I can't see any animation too.

My current worflow is: Begin->workflow fires when incident state is New or Active. ->End . I created an incident and changed the states to these 2 values, but no luck.

[image]

Let me know how to make sure that workflow is working.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a workflow executes, this is represented as a "Workflow Context."  You can look at the status of current or past contexts by navigating to "Workflow" > "All Contexts" in the nav menu.

That menu link will take you to a list of Workflow contexts (table name: wf_context).  You can locate your test executions by 2 columns, "Workflow version" and "Related record."  The Related record column will have the Incident number that triggered the workflow, and the Workflow version column will have the name of the test workflow you are working on.

Once you open up that record, there's a lot of useful information in there for examining the details of the workflow execution.  Among that info is a workflow log, activity history and transition history.  As you continue developing your workflow these will provide useful debugging data points if you encounter obstacles.

Workflow is a fairly deep concept, so I recommend glancing at this article as well, once your feet or sufficiently wet.

[Workflow Concepts](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Workflow_Concepts#gsc.tab=0)